# PHP - Foreach in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to do this. I can do it in Perl very easily, but cannot get it to work in Php:

I have about 6 fields on a webform that are required fields when they fill it out.

I want to put them into the array, like this: name => "error message here":

```
  $_ReqFields = array( 'name' => "Name is Required", 'field2' => "Field 2 is Required", 'field3' => "Field 3 is Required"); // ect...
```

But I cannot figure out the foreach to show the message if the field submitted was empty, here is what I have so far:

```
$_err = 0;
foreach ($reqFields as $__field) {
  if(empty($_REQUEST[$__field])) {
     $_err++;
     $_errMsg .= "{$reqFields{$__field}}" . "<br>";// ?? not sure how to do this to keep appending the error message for each field to the error message I'll show...
  }
}
```

so then I just have to check if $_err is still 0, if so, there were no errors, it is okay to process the request... but I cannot figure out what I did wrong there.

Can you help me please?

Thank you.
Rich

Comment: Why don't you put a comment as to why you gave this a negative? instead of just Clicking "negative" so I can improve my questions... I was stuck, why is that "bad"? at least I'm trying and not asking you to just do it for me, like some people do. I try it myself first, until I get frustrated.

I help people everyday with things they don't know, so what goes around comes around. I pay it forward all the time, offline...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your variable name "$_ReqFields" is not the same that you are using "$reqFields" maybe you need to rename $_ReqFields to $reqFields

Try this:

```
$reqFields = array(  'name' => 'Name is Required',
                     'field2' => 'Field 2 is Required',
                     'field3' => 'Field 3 is Required');
$_err = 0;
$_errMsg = '';
foreach ($reqFields as $field_name=>$error_msg) {
  if(isset($_REQUEST[$field_name]) && !$_REQUEST[$field_name]) {
     $_err++;
     $_errMsg .= $error_msg.'<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had them the same on my file, I just copied it over and chnaged up some stuff, did not realized I changed that too. I just took some private stuff out... sorry. My bad.

This did it for me: $field_name=>$error_msg

that part. I could not figure that out.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: I have to edited the code to do that more efficent, in php the simple quote is more faster than the double quote. And I figured out that I had the errorMsg redundant with "{$error_msg}" I have changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
$_err = 0;
$_errMsg = '';
foreach ($reqFields as $key=>$value) {
  if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
    $_err++;
    $_errMsg .= $value . '<br />';
  }
}
```

fixed foreach to look for keys and values and I guess the data is POST data so I changed $_REQUEST to $_POST. Also fixed $_errMsg